# Reading web page using HttpClient and HttpURLConnection returns empty string

Tags: java

I'm trying to develop an app that 
First connects to a http server (which is basically a proxy server running on port 8080) and saves its content to a string variable, then check to see if it contains some keywords, I tried using HttpClient and `HttpURLConnection` but both are returning empty strings with my URL http://myproxyaddress:8080/ , but returns the content of any other page like http://www.Google.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For why nothing returns from your proxy server: There's a lot of information you're losing by not also looking at the headers in the [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). I suggest you read up on this and take a look at HttpURLConnection